# grep with wildcards stored in a file

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I want grep to filter out lines by reading what it needs to filter out from a text file.

Here's what I give grep. It's stored in `foo.txt`:

```
".*  /Users/1337/X$"
".*  /Users/1337/R$"
".*  /Users/1337/W$"
```

And here's what it should filter from. It's stored in `bar.txt`:

```
1121cfccd5913f0a63fec40a6ffd44ea64f9dc135c66634ba001d10bcf4302a2  /Users/1337/R
dc460da4ad72c482231e28e688e01f2778a88ce31a08826899d54ef7183998b5  /Users/1337/T
4355a46b19d348dc2f57c046f8ef63d4538ebb936000f3c9ee954a27460dd865  /Users/1337/W
53c234e5e8472b6ac51c1ae1cab3fe06fad053beb8ebfd8977b010655bfdd3c3  /Users/1337/X
```

And this is the command I run:

```
cat bar.txt | grep -f foo.txt
```

I want it to output this:

```
1121cfccd5913f0a63fec40a6ffd44ea64f9dc135c66634ba001d10bcf4302a2  /Users/1337/R
4355a46b19d348dc2f57c046f8ef63d4538ebb936000f3c9ee954a27460dd865  /Users/1337/W
53c234e5e8472b6ac51c1ae1cab3fe06fad053beb8ebfd8977b010655bfdd3c3  /Users/1337/X
```

But it doesn't output anything. How can I fix this?

Mac OS X Yosemite, bash 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: You need to remove the quotes from the patterns (regular expressions, _not_ wildcard statements), so the `"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the doublequotes from `foo.txt`. Quotes are processed by the shell to protect special characters, but they're not actually part of the pattern, and treated literally when reading from a file.

If you can't modify the file, you can remove them on the fly using process substitution:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/' foo.txt) bar.txt
```

Comment: Wanted to post an answer with `-e`  but your answer simplifies it a great deal.

Comment: yeah, the whole reason `grep` has the `-f` option is so you don't have to do stuff like that (which wouldn't even have been possible before arrays were added to the shell).

Comment: Absolutely, removed the answer now.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{sub(/\$.*/,"",$NF);a[$NF];next} ($NF in a)' foo.txt  bar.txt
```