# expect certain number of characters in a wildcard with grep

Tags: bash, macos, unix, grep

I want to have a wildcard expect exactly 64 characters. Any less and the line is ignored. Any more and the line is ignored.

In `foo.txt` I have the following:

```
.*  /Users/1337/X$
.*  /Users/1337/R$
```

In `bar.txt` I have the following:

```
1121cfccd5913f0a63fec40a6ffd44ea64f9dc135c66634ba001d10bcf4302a2  /Users/1337/R
aa460da4af72c482231e28e688e01f2778a88ce31a08826899d54ef7183998b5  /  /Users/1337/R
4355a46b19d348dc2f57c046f8ef63d4538ebb936000f3c9ee954a27460dd865  /Users/1337/W
53c234e5e8472b6ac51c1ae1cab3fe06fad053beb8ebfd8977b010655bfdd3c3  /Users/1337/X
```

I was trying to use `grep` to filter out lines that match `/Users/1337/X` and `/Users/1337/R` exactly, with an SHA256 hash prepending it, which is always exactly 64 characters. This would prevent `grep` accidentally pulling line 2 from `bar.txt`, which does have `R` at the end and two spaces before `/Users`.

This command is the closest I have gotten, but, as stated earlier, this can cause `grep` to pick up the wrong lines:

```
cat bar.txt | grep -f foo.txt
```

I want it to output this:

```
1121cfccd5913f0a63fec40a6ffd44ea64f9dc135c66634ba001d10bcf4302a2  /Users/1337/R
53c234e5e8472b6ac51c1ae1cab3fe06fad053beb8ebfd8977b010655bfdd3c3  /Users/1337/X
```

But it outputs this instead:

```
1121cfccd5913f0a63fec40a6ffd44ea64f9dc135c66634ba001d10bcf4302a2  /Users/1337/R
aa460da4af72c482231e28e688e01f2778a88ce31a08826899d54ef7183998b5  /  /Users/1337/R
53c234e5e8472b6ac51c1ae1cab3fe06fad053beb8ebfd8977b010655bfdd3c3  /Users/1337/X
```

How can I fix this?

Mac OS X Yosemite, bash 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Why are you not using it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538345/grep-with-wildcards-stored-in-a-file

Comment: Do you mean `grep -E "^[0-9a-f]{64}" YourFile`?

Comment: @Inian Nothing is wrong with that answer. I did use it and it works great. The difference between that question and this one is that that question I wanted wildcards to work from a file. With this one I want them to expect 64 characters exactly, and nothing longer or shorter.

Comment: I have the answer. `foo.txt` needs to use `^.{64}` instead of `.*`, and I need to use this command: `cat bar.txt | egrep -f foo.txt`

Comment: It should and it does for me, because line 2 is `/  /Users.....` and I specified it to only look for `(SPACE)(SPACE)/Users......` with exactly 64 preceding characters. The extra slash and spaces in line 2 make it 67 preceding characters, which is wrong.

Comment: ok, I've posted my answer below.

Comment: `^.{64}` will also match something 65 characters long. You need to anchor it on the end too: `^.{64}$`... and if you really only want to match hex digits, then you should be using something more specific than `.`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hmm. Not for me. I added one random character to the beginning of line 1 in `bar.txt` and it didn't display that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure to use anchors in `foo.txt` to make sure to match complete line:

```
cat foo.txt
```

```
^.{64}  /Users/1337/X$
^.{64}  /Users/1337/R$
```

Then use this `grep` command to get your results:

```
grep -Ef foo.txt bar.txt
```

```
1121cfccd5913f0a63fec40a6ffd44ea64f9dc135c66634ba001d10bcf4302a2  /Users/1337/R
53c234e5e8472b6ac51c1ae1cab3fe06fad053beb8ebfd8977b010655bfdd3c3  /Users/1337/X
```

`-E` option is needed to support extended regex in `grep` command.

Comment: This works too, thanks for posting. Would you recommend I use that `grep` string instead of the `egrep` string I typed earlier?

Comment: Yes I will recommend grep as egrep is considered deprecated.